# Is self-fertilization in hermaphrodite animals an asexual or sexual reproduction?

Tags: reproduction

There are various **Hermaphrodite animals**, which can self fertilize.

So can this be called sexual reproduction because  there is fusion of gametes though from the same individual
? Or asexual because the involvement of a single parent(characteristics of asexual reproduction)?

There is a similar question- 
[Can Self-Fertilization in flowers be called asexual reproduction?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/76681/can-self-fertilization-in-flowers-be-called-asexual-reproduction)

Can I extend the same logic mentioned in the  [@Hawkeye's answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/76683/59661) to the given question link on the animal case above and say that it is a case of sexual reproduction?

Comment: You can (and should) extend the logic in Hawkeye's answer. Self-pollination is sexual reproduction.